# _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'xff'

Tags: python, io, stream

I am creating a tuple of two objects and pickling them. And when I try to unpickle them on the server side after passing it through sockets. It gives the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in my case this was appearing due to unexpectedly something else was also getting in the data after getting pickled and before being sent to other end. So I was trying to unpickle some garbage data. Thats why this contained some unidentified character.